# Display reason for 'nice question' et al

Tags: support, badges

When one gets a badge for passing a certain threshold for a question or answer ('Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer' among others, when one reloads an SE page, a banner at the top proclaims that a badge has been earned for the relevant question.

Also, in the recently deployed 'notifications' list, the badge and relevant question answer are displayed together.

But when one visits one's own user's badge list, there's just a list of the badges with no link/reference to the earning question/answer.

Can some reference/link to the reason why a badge was earned be given for a badge? Rolling over the badge gives the meaning of the badge, and clicking goes to the badge's description page. Maybe just add the reason in the rollover?

Comment: I'm so confused. How is reason different than meaning? The notification gives you the post you earned the badge on, and the rollover in the badges list gives you a description of what earns you the badge. What else, exactly, do you need?

Comment: Once the banner notification goes away, I was saying there is no way later to see what event earned you that badge. I realize now (from the answer) that visiting the badge on the user profile tells you exactly what I am asking for.

Answer (score 10):

If you click the badge in your profile, you get a list of all of the posts for which you earned that badge.

Comment: Argh..I should have noticed that. I think that suffices.

Comment: Have a "nice answer" badge ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I already noticed the irony of getting a nice answer badge for a question about nice answer badges